# How can I change an apostrophe into a single unit instead of 3 bytes? (\342 \200 \231) using C

Tags: c, unicode, counting, text-manipulation

hopefully someone can help me out here. I'm trying to created a program that counts the number of words, vowels, special characters etc. After doing some digging, I've realized the values being stored for a single apostrophe is counting for 3 positions where it should only be one. If anyone knows how to solve this I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks!!

```
for (int i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    if (sentence[i] == 'a' || sentence[i] == 'e' || sentence[i] == 'i' || sentence[i] == 'o' || sentence[i] == 'u'||
        sentence[i] == 'A' || sentence[i] == 'E' || sentence[i] == 'I' || sentence[i] == 'O' || sentence[i] == 'U') {
        ++numVowels;
    } else if (sentence[i] == ' ') {
        ++numSpaces;
    } else {
        ++numSpecials;
        printf("%c\n",sentence[i]);
    }

    if ((sentence[i] == ' ' && sentence[i+1] != ' ') || (sentence[i] != '\0' && sentence[i+1] == '\0')) {
        ++numWords;
    }
}

printf("Number of words: %d\n", numWords);
printf("Number of spaces: %d\n", numSpaces);
printf("Number of vowels: %d\n", numVowels);
printf("Number of consonants and special characters: %d\n", (numSpecials));
```

Comment: If you need to handle unicode, consider converting to UTF-32 first. Use some Unicode library to do this. You could also convert to Latin1 for example, ignoring chars which don't exist in Latin1, but still, use a library. 7 bit ASCII conversion you could do by hand sensibly, I suppose.

Comment: VTC as a typo error - interestingly a typo error in data input.

Answer (score 4):

`\342 \200 \231` is `E2 80 99` in hex, which is the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded form of [U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) which is **not** an apostrophe. It's one of the [smart quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_quotes) in Unicode

UTF-8 is a variable-width encoding, so you need to skip the whole code point (which can be encoded by multiple bytes). That's simple to do once you learn the encoding rule of UTF-8 (minus the hard things like shortest sequence or invalid sequence check...)

However since you want to count *words, vowels, special characters* which is too broad. How would you count characters such as á, è, ü...? What are considered as special characters? There are tens of thousands of each of them and you won't be able to work on a general solution without any external libraries

If you just want to do that as an exercise, consider limiting the input to **ASCII only**

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figured out what was happening.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Unicode programming. What you have there is a "RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK", possibly from some kind of word document editor as they will commonly auto-replace `"`, `'`, etc. with the more specific one based on context.

If you need to deal with Unicode, you will probably want to use a Unicode library or the data from the unicode.org [releases](https://www.unicode.org/releases/index.html). While decoding UTF-8 itself is easy, questions like "is this a punctuation mark?", "is this a space?", "is this part of a letter?" etc. are not.

The specific data you want to get I believe is the "Unicode Character Category". The top most categories being:

- Letter
- Mark ([combining characters](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm), etc.)
- Number
- Punctuation
- Symbol
- Seperator (spaces, paragraph, etc.)
- Other (control codes, etc.)

There are also many subcategories, although I don't think you need them. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm seems to have a nice list to investigate online.

The main problem feature is probably the "vowels" count as that doesn't translate nicely to all languages/scripts. Potentially you could "decompose" stuff like Á and only count the resulting AEIOU letters for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is probably using [UTF-8 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Here is the list of characters that can be stored in a single byte: http://www.asciitable.com/

Are you using the same apostrophe as there?

`'`

If not, then you should handle it as multiple bytes.

Comment: It's just when the sentence taken in has an apostrophe, the same as you're using above. I want the count to increase only by one instead of 3 when it is used.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me about the apostrophe being a different code. I was using a sample sentence from a word document I copied and pasted which created the issue but manually typing in the sentence fixed the problem!